# How not to echo a value if already in the input value?

Tags: php

I have some values in a custom field:

```
save_post = "1200"
```

Or it could be, since I need a list eventually:

```
save_post = "1200, 1460, 1334"
```

Now when I load the page, I get these `values` and I set them in an `input field`, and I also add the `current value id` from the `current page`:

```
$allPosts = $userPosts.", ".$postid;
```

Where `$userPosts`is the single value or the value list from the custom field, and `$postid` is the current page id I want to add.

The result is:

```
<input type="text" value="1200, 23138, 23138, 23138">
```

I would always get duplicate values each time I hit the update submit button as the page refreshes itself:

```
<form id="saveId" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="save_post_value" value="<?php echo $userPosts.", ".$postid;  ?>"> 
  <button  type="submit" class="save_post btn btn-danger">Update</button>
</form>
```

How can I check if a value is already in the input and if so, don't echo it?

A way would be to have them in an `Array` and then output in the `input field` the `unique array`, not sure if there is a shorter way.

Trying:

```
$allPosts = array($userPosts.", ".$postid); 
$allPosts = array_unique($allPosts); 

<input type="text" name="save_post_value" value="<?php foreach ($allPosts as $value) { echo $value; } ?>">
```

Also:

```
$allPosts = array($userPosts.", ".$postid); 
$allPosts = array_unique($allPosts); 
$allPosts = explode(", ", $allPosts);
<input type="text" name="save_post_value" value="<?php echo $allPosts; ?>"
```

And tried with `implode()` too:

```
$allPosts = array($userPosts.", ".$postid); 
$allPosts = array_unique($allPosts); 
$allPosts = implode(", ", $allPosts);
<input type="text" name="save_post_value" value="<?php echo $allPosts; ?>"
```

Comment: array would be better use in_array function to check

Comment: @SanoojT updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic example, but I think that this can be useful for your needs:

```
<?php
// Input data
$userPosts = '19000, 23138, 23138';
$postid = '23138';

// With array
$userPosts = str_replace(' ', '', $userPosts);
if (empty($userPosts)) {
    $a = array();
} else {
    $a = explode(',', $userPosts);
}   
$a = array_unique($a, SORT_STRING);
if (in_array($postid, $a) === false) {
    $a[] = $postid;
}
$userPosts = implode(', ', $a);
echo 'Result using array: '.$userPosts.'</br>';
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

It is possible to use a function. Check for empty posts is made using `empty()`.

```
<?php
function getUniquePosts($xposts, $xid) {
    $xposts = str_replace(' ', '', $xposts);
    if (empty($xposts)) {
        $a = array();
    } else {
        $a = explode(',', $xposts);
    }   
    $a = array_unique($a, SORT_STRING);
    if (in_array($xid, $a) === false) {
        $a[] = $xid;
    }
    $xposts = implode(', ', $a);
    $xposts = ltrim($xposts, ",");

    return $xposts;
}

$userPosts = '19000, 23138, 23138';
$postId = '23138';
echo getUniquePosts($userPosts, $postId).'</br>';
?>
```

Then when loading form you can try with this:

```
...
$a = array_unique($a, SORT_STRING); 
...
update_user_meta($user_id, 'save_post', getUniquePosts($a, $user_id));
```

Comment: I still get a duplicate value while doing:                           `$postid = $post->ID;
                          $userPosts= get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', TRUE );
           $a = explode(',', $userPosts);
           if (in_array($postid, $a) === false) {
            $a[] = $postid;
           }
           $userPosts = implode(',', $a);` and then `<input type="text" name="save_post_value" value="<?php echo $userPosts; ?>"> `

Comment: if I echo those values I get `$postid = 23138` `$userPosts = 19000, 23138, 23138`

Comment: if the custom field is empty, the currently id is displayed in the input but it has the comma at the start `,19000` it should be `19000`

Comment: `$userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");`

Comment: @rob.m         I've updated the answer to check for empty $userPosts.

Comment: thanks but the issue is `$userPosts = implode(', ', $a);` because if we only one value, it will start with a comma, i have provided the solution in the comment, add it to your answer

Comment: actually it is still giving me duplicates

Comment: basically if I do: `$a = array_unique($a, SORT_STRING); update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $a );` before the submit, in order to update the field first with unique values, it doesn't work

Comment: @rob.m          If you want to achieve this, I think is better to define a function. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code on checking duplicate values after submission:

```
$userPosts = '19000, 23138, 23138';
$postid = '23138';
$pattern = "/(?:^|\W)".$postid."(?:$|\W)/";

if(preg_match($pattern, $userPosts, $matches))
{
    print 'There is a duplicate '.rtrim($matches[0] , ",");
}
```

Basically I reuse Zhorov's variables but on his approach he put it in an array, and then check if that array contains the submitted value, mine is almost the same as his approach but instead of putting it in an array; I use regex to determine is the value existed in the string.

Comment: also if I do: `$a = array_unique($a, SORT_STRING); update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $a );` before the `submit`, in order to `update the field first` with `unique values`, it doesn't work

Comment: If you don't want to output the matches, then do whatever you need to accomplish inside the code block of the If statement. or simple revise it to and add else statement.